# Поместить массив в JSON формат

Tags: массивы, json, perl

Есть ajax запрос, который идёт в perl скрипт, из которого необходимо получить данные в формате JSON, чтобы далее обработать их на клиенте. Однако пока не пойму, как засунуть массив в JSON формат. Вот код:

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie;
use DBI;
use JSON;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
$cgi->header( -type => 'text/html', -charset => 'utf-8' );

my $db = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:db', 'login', 'password');
my $sth = $db->prepare('SET NAMES UTF8');

my @hash;
my $i = 0;

my $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");
    $sth->execute;
    while(my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
        $hash[$i] = {
            id => $$ref[0],
            user_id => $$ref[1],
            title => $$ref[2],
            text => $$ref[3],
            tags => $$ref[4],
            date => $$ref[5]
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
my $encoded = $json->encode(@hash);

print $encoded;
```

Ругается на строчку my $encoded = $json->encode([[[@hash](/users/1403/hash3r)](/users/1403/hash3r)](/users/1403/hash3r));

```
[error] Usage: JSON::XS::encode(self, scalar)
```

Что исправить? Если необходимо могу привести аналог в php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну для начала было бы неплохо показать текст ошибки, телепатов, как водится, нет.

```
my $encoded = $json->encode(\@hash);
```

Comment: Текст ошибки написал.

Comment: попробуйте так

my $encoded = $json->encode(\@hash);

Comment: Наконец-то! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Замечание не по теме: с помощью модуля [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) можно писать более компактный и удобочитаемый код, чем у вас. Например, получить результат запроса в массив хэшей можно так:

```
my @hashes = @{
    $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
        'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15',
        { Slice => {} }
    )
};
```

Кроме того, вам потом, для `$json->encode` понадобится не сам массив, а ссылка на него — можно написать ещё компактнее:

```
my $hashes = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
    'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15',
    { Slice => {} }
);
# ...
my $encoded = $json->encode($hashes);
```

---

P. S. Выше в коде тоже странность: вы готовите запрос: `my $sth = $db->prepare('SET NAMES UTF8');` но забываете его выполнить. Этот кусок тоже можно упростить:

```
$db->do('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Метод `do()` объединяет в себе `prepare()` и `execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $encoded = $json->encode(\%hash);
```